# Asymptotics of coefficients

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, asymptotics

This is a question that asks the reader for a $strategy$ to solve a particular problem. I cannot solve this problem myself so I am looking around for general methods one might use to confront it with. Suppose
$$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+...,  g(x)=b_0+b_1x_...$$
and given
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{g^{(n)}(x)}=1$$
With the additional
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$$ and $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=1 $$
for all natural $n$. Prove
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$$

I would like to know your general thoughts about approaching this type of problem. Any insights however small will be much appreciated. Although this is seemingly a problem in real analysis, I have tagged complex analysis because solutions may well involve it.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Are you allowed to assume that $\lim_{\nearrow 1}f^{(n)}(x)$ and $\lim_{\nearrow 1}g^{(n)}(x)$ converge on their own, or is it just the ratio that converges?

Comment: In the case I am looking at, they don't converge

Answer (score 3):

Under the given assumptions,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$$

need not hold. Counterexample:

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{1}{1-x^2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2k},\\
g(x) &= f(x) + e^x.
\end{align}$$

We have $\dfrac{a_n}{b_n} = 0$ for all odd $n$, but nevertheless

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{g^{(n)}(x)} = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{f^{(n)}(x)+e^x} = 1$$

for all $n$, since $\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \lvert f^{(n)}(x)\rvert = +\infty$, while $e^x$ remains bounded.

You need some further conditions to reach the conclusion.

Comment: Yes I feared this was the case. Additional conditions that one may add is that lim a_n/a_{n-1}=1. I will add this to the question but thanks for this response. If you can find a counter example to this additional condition I will consider the case closed.

Comment: I tend to believe that with the additional conditions, it holds. But I have no idea for a proof yet.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly suppose that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two polynomials, and let their degree be $c$ and $d$, respectively. Suppose $ d \gt c$, you get
$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\frac{f^d(x)}{g^d(x)} = \frac{0}{d!\cdot b_d} = 0 \ne 1$, so it's impossible that $ d \gt c$; obviously you can use the same proof to prove that it's impossible that $ c\gt d$.

Now, since $c=d$, $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\frac{f^c(x)}{g^c(x)} = \frac{c!\cdot a_c}{c!\cdot b_c} = \frac{a_c}{b_c} = 1$ , so $a_c$ = $b_c$.

Similarly, $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\frac{f^{c-1}(x)}{g^{c-1}(x)} = \frac{(c-1)!\cdot a_{c-1}+c!\cdot x\cdot a_c}{(c-1)!\cdot b_{c-1}+c!\cdot x\cdot b_c} = \frac{a_{c-1}+a_c}{b_{c-1}+b_c} = 1$, which means that

$a_{c-1}+a_c = b_{c-1}+b_c$

$a_{c-1} = b_{c-1}$.

Clearly you go on with the same "strategy", and you'll obtain that $a_i$ = $b_i$ for all $i$ such that  $0\le i \le c$, so $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$.

Comment: I don't think that $f$ and $g$ are supposed to be polynomials here....

Comment: Well, $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+...,  g(x)=b_0+b_1x_...$ is usually the most used method to refer to polynomials...

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific. I mean I think $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots$ is a *power series* in $x$, i.e., $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i$. Similarly for $g$.

Comment: A polynomial is something like this: $a_n\cdot x^n + a_{n-1}\cdot x^{n-1} + ... a_{1}\cdot x^{1} + a_0$ and can be written as $\sum_{i=0} ^n a_i \cdot x^i$, just like a *power series*...

Comment: Yes, I know that a polynomial is a power series, but the converse is not true. Not all power series are polynomials. The question is asking about power series generally, not about polynomials. Your argument works for polynomials, but not for more general (i.e., non-polynomial) power series.

Comment: So ... you mean that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ goes to infinity, and they don't stop at $x_c⋅a_c$ and $x_d⋅b_d$: now I understand...I'll work on this..